# Is it a bad idea to use visualizations in studying linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, education, visualization

many concepts in linear algebra are explained using visualizations. However, many practical applications of linear algebra use spaces whose dimension is larger than 3 which you cannot visualize. When I try to learn some concept of linear algebra using visualization I find it difficult to think in higher dimensions. So, I thought that may be it is a bad idea to use visualizations and always try to learn linear algebra without using visualizations. Do you agree with this?
Thanks

Comment: I think the obvious answer is "it's fine if it works for you". Obviously, we can't visualise 4d space but that's not to say visualisations aren't useful where they are appropriate.

Comment: We use visualizations to get an intuition as to what is going on in the lower dimensional case, and then see if we can "follow our nose" to find the correct solution in the higher dimensional case. True, sometimes the visualizations in lower dimensional cases can be misleading, but usually trying to get a mental grasp on something via visualizations works in our favor.

Comment: I myself often find visualizations useful even in infinite dimensions.  In many cases the real action is taking place in $2$ or $3$ dimensions.  You just have to not let the extra unseen dimensions bother you.

Comment: Using your intuition, whether visual intuition or other kinds, can be a tool as well as a crutch. To say that it's a bad idea is too limiting.

Comment: Visualization is great, but sometimes misleading.  To give an example: there are metric spaces in which two spheres which share a point one is contained in the other. Or two open spheres of the same radius are contained is a closed sphere of the same radius. -- Quite counterintuitive, isn't it?